# Facebook Integration With Android Application

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am integrating facebook sdk 3.21.1, All things are going well but there is only one issue.
When i click on share button it will prompt me a dialog(In case of FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder) for posting something. If i press Back button then onCompleteMethod of com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.OnCompleteListener will invoked and i am not able to get the event, Either it is successfully posted or pressed back button.
Because i wanna show the exact toast message to the user.

This is my Code:-

```
/**
 * Handle Facebook Sharing
 * 
 * Take Decision for sharing approach.
 */
private void handleFacebookSharing() 
{
    //Show Hash Key
    showHashKey(this);

    //Can Present Share Dialog(Facebook Application is installed or not) 
    boolean canPresentShareDialog = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG);

    if (canPresentShareDialog) 
    {
        //Publish the Post Using the Share Dialog
        FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder shareDialogBuilder = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(ShareActivity.this);

        //Set Link
        shareDialogBuilder.setLink(ShareActivity.this.getString(R.string.share_link));

        //Set Caption
        shareDialogBuilder.setCaption(getString(R.string.share_caption));

        //Set Description
        shareDialogBuilder.setDescription(getString(R.string.share_description));

        //Get Facebook Dialog
        FacebookDialog facebookDialog = shareDialogBuilder.build();

        //Track Pending Dialog Call
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(facebookDialog.present());
    }
    else
    {
        if(activeSession == null || !activeSession.isOpened())
        {
            //Open Active Session
            activeSession = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
        else
        {
            //Show Web Dialog
            showWebDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

And onActivityResult method:-

```
uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent, new FacebookDialog.Callback() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) 
        {
            //Show Toast
            UIUtil.showToast(R.string.toast_message_share_error_posting);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) 
        {
            //Show Toast
            UIUtil.showToast(R.string.toast_message_share_success_post);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys after spending a lot of time i found a solution, we can check that story is cancelled or posted by using this code.

```
@Override
    public void onComplete(PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) 
    {
        //Get Native Dialog Did Complete
        boolean didComplete = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogDidComplete(data);

        if(didComplete)
        {
            //Get Native Dialog Completion Gesture
            String nativeDialogCompletionGesture = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogCompletionGesture(data);

            if (nativeDialogCompletionGesture == null || FacebookDialog.COMPLETION_GESTURE_CANCEL.equals(nativeDialogCompletionGesture))
            {
                //Show Publish Cancel Toast
                UIUtil.showToast(R.string.toast_message_share_publish_cancelled);                                               
            }
            else
            {
                //Show Success Post Toast
                UIUtil.showToast(R.string.toast_message_share_success_post);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Show Publish Cancel Toast
            UIUtil.showToast(R.string.toast_message_share_publish_cancelled);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) 
    {
        //Show Toast
        UIUtil.showToast(R.string.toast_message_share_error_posting);
    }
```